# Is it possible to copy a table in one gcp project into another gcp project through java code. Note that but projects are not in same organization

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to copy a dataset from one project to another using java. I figured I should at least start by being able to move at least a table first. The source project is in one gcp for one organization and the destination project is in a gcp for another organization

I have tried looking through big query's documentation.

Comment: Did try this example? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-copy-table#bigquery_copy_table-java but add the "project_id" as addition first parameter in the method Table.of to select the correct project, dataset and table. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to copy a dataset from one project to another project.

1. If the dataset is in different region , then use the BigQuery Data transfer service
   (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dts-introduction)(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/datatransfer/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) .
2. Another way would be to copy tables from your source project to a GCS folder and then from GCS folder to the destination project.